# Firebase returns permission denied on random setValue() child data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm testing Firebase Rules to add more security to the data entry in the Firebase database. I would like to ensure that:

1. Only Firebase Authenticated "users" can read/write their own account information into "accounts"
2. only Firebase Authenticated "users" can read/write their own character data into "messages".

**For this purpose I have written the following Rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "account": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"           
      }     
    },  
    "messages": {
        "$message_id": {
        ".read": "auth !== null",
        ".write": "auth.uid === newData.child('_uid').val() && 
            root.child('account').hasChild(auth.uid) === true"  
      },
    }
  }
}
```

The above rules look to be correct, however I get **"failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied"** on (3) of the "messages" child nodes that I am pushing in for a logged-in user account.

**Here is a code snippet of my push to firebase method:**

```
public void saveToFirebase(){
  String echo = "";
  String _uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
  DatabaseReference mCurrentRecord = mFirebaseGame.push();
  Log.d(LOG, "User is " + _uid + "\nNew record ID: " + mCurrentRecord.getKey());

  gameCharacter.map.put("_uid", _uid);

  try{
    for(String keys : gameCharacter.map.keySet()){
      echo += keys + ":" + gameCharacter.map.get(keys) + "\n";
      mCurrentRecord.child(keys).setValue(gameCharacter.map.get(keys));
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    error = e.toString();
  }
}
```

**And here is the permission-denied error that I am getting:**

[image: Permission denied for txtStr, txtCharName and txtEner]

I cannot follow why I would get permission denied errors only for the child nodes "txtStr, txtCharName and txtEner", while the rest have been successfully pushed to the database.

I hope you can point out if I miss anything in my Firebase Rules structure or anything. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not immediately sure why your current code is failing. But instead of looping over the map, why don't you simply call `mCurrentRecord.setValue(gameCharacter.map)`?

Comment: You are correct @Frank van Puffelen, the error was corrected when I put all of gameCharacter.map in setValue(), all in one go.

Comment: Good to hear raiser00!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to this question is as @Frank van Puffelen pointed out, by inserting ALL child node values at once by calling **mCurrentRecord.setValue(gameCharacter.map)**, and not to iterate putting data to setValue() separately.

This is because of the "messages" Rule, which checks for a group of bulk-inserted child nodes in newData.

```
"messages": {
   "$message_id": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      ".write": "auth.uid === newData.child('_uid').val() && 
         root.child('account').hasChild(auth.uid) === true"  
   },
}
```